# Meaning of icons in Eclipse Type Hierarchy window

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, the *Java Method Override Indicator* is the little upwards arrow next to a method in the Type Hierarchy view.

A solid arrow means a method overrides an existing method lower in the hierarchy.

What does the hollow arrow mean?

Do annotations effect either arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hollow" or white, as I perceive it, arrow means that this method does not override a super class method but implements specified in an interface.

Annotations should not have anything to do with that. There is only a preference setting in the `java / editor / save actions` section that defines whether to automatically insert override annotations, but that is only semantically, but not technically related to the arrows mentioned

Comment: So it does!  Thank you.  Now suppose Class A extends Class B, Class A implements interface 1, and interface 1 extends interface 2, and Class B implements interface 2.  Further suppose there is a method foo declared in all 4 locations.  Should the Class A view show it as an extends (solid) or implments (hollow)?

Comment: extends is "more important than" implements, so green it is. (just tried it, eclipse seems to agree with me :-))